# Calling the data from the database which is from last 6 month specifically

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I know how to call the data within the last 6 month with this SQL code of mine.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE 
registered_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

The problem is listing out the COUNT (*) data specifically for the month, example:

```
12 = January
10 = February
3 = March
```

And so on so forth. I am trying to implement it into a PHP graph.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of the mysql [`MONTH`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php) function and [`GROUP BY`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(registered_date) FROM user
WHERE registered_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) GROUP BY MONTH(registered_date)
```

Comment: Oof, I just found out that too. It's been awhile since I last used the SQL, got a little rusty here. By the way thanks for the feedback!